# How to access the online database in android?

Tags: android

I am making one app which submits the registration form by users and updates the form data into the database maintained at the remote server.

I am using my local host as a server. My app works fine when tested on a emulator.
But when I run the app on my phone having different internet connection, app works fine with no error but the database on my localhost is not updated.

Follow my code below.

MainActivity.java

```
package com.mits_form;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.app.ProgressDialog;
 import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.util.Log;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

// Progress Dialog
private ProgressDialog pDialog;

JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
EditText inputName;
EditText inputPrice;
EditText inputDesc;

// url to create new product
private static String urlcreateproduct = "http://192.168.1.145/androidconnect/createproduct.php";

// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    pDialog.setMessage("Creating Product..");
    pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
    pDialog.setCancelable(true);

    // Edit Text
    inputName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    inputPrice = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    inputDesc = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);

    // Create button

    try
    {
    Button btnCreateProduct = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

    // button click event

    btnCreateProduct.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // creating new product in background thread
            new CreateNewProduct().execute();
        }
    });
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Log.e("MITS FORM", ex.toString());
    }

}
  // Background Async Task to Create new product

    class CreateNewProduct extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
 /*
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Creating Product..");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);*/
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * Creating product
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        try{
        String name = inputName.getText().toString();
        String price = inputPrice.getText().toString();
        String description = inputDesc.getText().toString();

        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("price", price));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("description", description));

        // getting JSON Object
        // Note that create product url accepts POST method
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(urlcreateproduct,"POST", params);

        // check log cat fro response
        Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

        // check for success tag
        try {
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " form submitted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                // successfully created product
              //  Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AllProductsActivity.class);
                //startActivity(i);

                // closing this screen

               // finish();
            } else {
                // failed to create product
            }
        } catch (JSONException e)
        {
            System.out.println("in  catch of json exception");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext()," in catch",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.e("MITS", ex.toString());
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog once done
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"finished...",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        pDialog.dismiss();
    }

    }
}
```

JSONParser.java

```
package com.mits_form;

/**
   * Created by vanja on 3/29/14.
 */

import android.util.Log;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
 import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils;
 import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
 import org.json.JSONException;
 import org.json.JSONObject;

 import java.io.BufferedReader;
 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.io.InputStream;
 import java.io.InputStreamReader;
  import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
  import java.util.List;

   public class JSONParser {

static InputStream is = null;
static JSONObject jObj = null;
static String json = "";

// constructor
public JSONParser() {

}

// function get json from url
// by making HTTP POST or GET mehtod
public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
                                  List<NameValuePair> params) {

    // Making HTTP request
    try {

        // check for request method
        if(method == "POST"){
            // request method is POST
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        }else if(method == "GET"){
            // request method is GET
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
            url += "?" + paramString;
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
        }

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;

    }
}
```

Please guide. 
Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: I don't see anything related to updating a database here. Also, are you sure there is no error? post the logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your URL is internal and therefore cannot be accessed from network outside. You need to assign an external IP to it. `http://192.168.1.145/`

Comment: Would that matter if his device is on the same network as his computer hosting the local server though?

Comment: the user mentioned that he/she runs the app having different internet connection, so I assume that his device is not running on the same network.

Comment: ah yeah duh; then they need to host it definitely.

Answer (score 0):

I personally would use a sqllite db but maybe this [link will](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidJSON/article.html) be of help to you